# How to handle foreign language characters in dynamic query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Update query is not working for foreign chars in particular column. I am getting chars like "Гроздановски" and they are not able to processed in dynamic query.

Dynamic query for update is causing error for the set of these chars.

Comment: I suggest you make yourself familiar with Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

There is an special notation used to declare [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) strings - `N'Гроздановски'`. If you're using `NVARCHAR` - it is Unicode-friendly by default so `N''` will be redundant in this case.

Take a look at an article [Why to use `N` prefix in SQL?](http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html)

If this wont help - provide query that is not working.